# How to know what version of jre is used on netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

My computer has 2 jre folders in java folder, which are jre1.8.0_331 and jre1.8.0_333. How can I know what version of jre is using?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by taking a look at the NetBeans menu: Tools > Java Platforms. Also take a look at Help > About. Do either of these answer your question?

Comment: Some IDEs come with their own JDK bundled within, used for its own internal operations. The external JDK(s) are used for compiling and running your project.

Comment: @cliff2310 It is not meaningful to provide a minimal reproducible example for this particular question. The OP is asking how to determine the exact JRE version being used by NetBeans, and providing sample code cannot possibly help.

Comment: As already mentioned in an earlier comment, **Help > About** will tell you which JRE is being used by NetBeans. If that resolves your issue please consider posting (and accepting) an answer, since answered questions are more helpful to the community than solutions buried in the comments.